# Efficiently splitting a character vector

Tags: r, list, split

I have this style of a character vector:

```
vec <- c("id a; sex m; age 16; type 1;","id a; sex m; age 16;","id a; sex m; age 16; type 3")
```

Every element in `vec` is a "; " separated list of attributes where the each attribute has the "key value" format (the "; " character can only appear as the separator).

So the first list of attributes is:
id=a
sex=m
age=16
type=1

Note that different elements in `vec` may have slightly different attributes.

I'm looking for an efficient way to split `vec` to a list of lists. Each element in the outer list is a list of all attribute values where the element names are the attribute keys. This means that the length of the outer list will be the length of the elements of `vec` and the length of each inner list will the the length of attributes.

I currently have this implementation, which help to understand the output I need:

```
attributes.list <- sapply(vec, function(x) strsplit(x, split = "(\\;)(\\s+)?", perl = TRUE)[[1]])
attributes.lol <- lapply(attributes.list, function(x) {
  attribute.mat <- sapply(x, function(y) strsplit(y, split = " ")[[1]])
  colnames(attribute.mat) <- NULL
  attribute.list <- as.list(attribute.mat[2,])
  names(attribute.list) <- attribute.mat[1,]
  return(attribute.list)
})

> attributes.lol[[1]]
$id
[1] "a"

$sex
[1] "m"

$age
[1] "16"

$type
[1] "1"
```

The length of `vec` in reality is very long (~million elements) so I was wondering if there's a more efficient way to achieve this.

Comment: Can the value ever *contain* `;` (e.g. as part of a string, or escaped)?

Comment: Which part of the code is a bottleneck?

Comment: The answer to Konrad Rudolph's question is no. "; " can only appear as the separator.

Comment: You don't need `sapply` when creating "attributes.list"; `strsplit(vec, ..` suffices. Perhaps, if your "vec" is always and exactly in this format, you coulse `strsplit` on `"(\\s+)|(\\;)(\\s+)?"` once and then use the `x[c(TRUE, FALSE)]` as the "names" of the `x[c(FALSE, TRUE)]` in each element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following uses only base R.  Append a semicolon onto each record, split the records at semicolon, remove leading and trailing whitespace, replace the space with a colon and space and read in using `read.dcf`.  This gives a matrix `m` which we convert to a data frame and use type.convert to get the right types.  (If a matrix is sufficient then omit the second line.)

```
m <- read.dcf(textConnection(sub(" ",": ",trimws(unlist(strsplit(paste0(vec, ";"),";"))))))
as.data.frame(lapply(as.data.frame(m, stringsAsFactors = FALSE), type.convert))
```

giving:

```
  id sex age type
1  a   m  16    1
2  a   m  16   NA
3  a   m  16    3
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest a combination of "iotools" and "data.table", something along the lines of this:

```
library(iotools)
library(data.table)
melt(data.table(ind = seq_along(vec), trimws(mstrsplit(vec, ";"))),
     "ind", na.rm = TRUE)[
      , c("key", "val") := tstrsplit(value, " ", TRUE)][
        , c("variable", "value") := NULL][]
```

Or, if you want a "wide" form (like @GGrothendieck's answer):

```
dcast(
  melt(data.table(ind = seq_along(vec), trimws(mstrsplit(vec, ";"))),
       "ind", na.rm = TRUE)[
         , c("key", "val") := tstrsplit(value, " ", TRUE)][
           , c("variable", "value") := NULL][], ind ~ key, value.var = "val")
```

---

I suggest the above because you mention that you want an efficient approach. Compare the following:

Sample data length 3, approximately 100000, and approximately 1 million.

```
vec <- c("id a; sex m; age 16; type 1;","id a; sex m; age 16;","id a; sex m; age 16; type 3")
v100k <- rep(vec, ceiling(100000/length(vec)))
v1M <- rep(vec, ceiling(1000000/length(vec)))
```

The approaches we want to test:

```
library(iotools)
library(data.table)

funAM_l <- function(invec) {
  melt(data.table(ind = seq_along(invec), trimws(mstrsplit(invec, ";"))), "ind", na.rm = TRUE)[
    , c("key", "val") := tstrsplit(value, " ", TRUE)][
      , c("variable", "value") := NULL][]
}

funAM_w <- function(invec) dcast(funAM_l(invec), ind ~ key, value.var = "val")

funMT <- function(v) {
  z <- strsplit(v, split = "(\\;)(\\s+)?", perl = TRUE)
  lapply(z,function(s) {v <- unlist(strsplit(s,' ')); setNames(as.list(v[c(F,T)]),v[c(T,F)]) })
}

funF <- function(invec) rbindlist(lapply(invec, function(x) { fread(gsub(";", "\n", x)) }), idcol = TRUE)

funGG <- function(invec) read.dcf(textConnection(sub(" ",": ",trimws(unlist(strsplit(paste0(invec, ";"),";"))))))
```

My suggestion isn't going to win any races with a small vector:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(funAM_l(vec), funAM_w(vec), funF(vec), funGG(vec), funMT(vec))
# Unit: microseconds
#          expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq      max neval
#  funAM_l(vec) 1474.163 1525.3765 1614.28414 1573.6325 1601.3815 2828.481   100
#  funAM_w(vec) 3293.376 3482.9510 3741.30381 3553.7240 3714.1730 6787.863   100
#     funF(vec)  690.761  729.4900  830.61645  756.4610  777.6725 4083.904   100
#    funGG(vec)  182.281  209.8405  220.46376  220.8055  232.1820  280.788   100
#    funMT(vec)   57.288   76.5225   84.81496   83.2755   90.3120  166.352   100
```

But look at what happens when we scale up the vectors:

```
system.time(funAM_l(v100k))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.24    0.00    0.24 
system.time(funAM_w(v100k))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.296   0.000   0.296 
system.time(funMT(v100k))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   1.768   0.000   1.768 
system.time(funF(v100k))
#    user  system elapsed 
#  21.960   0.136  22.068 
system.time(funGG(v100k))
#    user  system elapsed 
#  30.968   0.004  30.940
```

Here's how it performs on a vector of length 1 million.

```
system.time(funAM_w(v1M))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   4.316   0.092   4.402
```

---

My other suggestion was going to be to look at `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package. That is a little bit better performing than @Marat's approach.

Here it is on 1 million values:

```
library(splitstackshape)
system.time(dcast(
  cSplit(cSplit(data.table(ind = seq_along(v1M), v1M), "v1M", ";", "long"), "v1M", " "), 
  ind ~ v1M_1, value.var = "v1M_2"))
#    user  system elapsed 
#  13.744   0.156  13.882
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this approach, which is in line with the  @alexis_laz suggestions:

Setup:

```
vec <- c("id a; sex m; age 16; type 1;","id a; sex m; age 16;","id a; sex m; age 16; type 3")

v <- rep(vec,1e5)
```

Code:

```
z <- strsplit(v, split = "(\\;)(\\s+)?", perl = TRUE)

out <- lapply(z,function(s) {v <- unlist(strsplit(s,' ')); setNames(as.list(v[c(F,T)]),v[c(T,F)]) })
```

Answer (score 1):

Even this does not bring you the same output you can try substituting the ";" as follows:

```
require(data.table)
l <- lapply(vec, function(x){
  fread(gsub(";", "\n", x))
})
```

which gives you a list which you can then combine via

```
rbindlist(l, idcol = TRUE)
```

This results in:

```
   .id   id  a
1:   1  sex  m
2:   1  age 16
3:   1 type  1
4:   2  sex  m
5:   2  age 16
6:   3  sex  m
7:   3  age 16
8:   3 type  3
```

Comment: Calling `fread` a million times is not necessarily going to be fast, is it?